# Trying to do the calculation and its not calculating the average and curve

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    SortedList<string, double> num2 = new SortedList<string, double>();    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        double score = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        num2.Add(name, score);                       
    }


    foreach (var listItem in num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{listItem.Key} - {listItem.Value}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Name:");
    double average = num2.Sum(item => +item.Value) / 5;
    double curve = 75 - average;
    Console.WriteLine($"{curve}");
    Console.ReadLine();                        
}
```

Basically I am trying to calculate the average to get the curve, which is subtracted by 75. Once I did this it didn't calculate the average. The average = 0 not the set value that the user types. Do you know how I fix that.

Comment: Please clear your question. What bug you want to fix ??  If you want to know why your code is not getting output just remove "+" form double average = num2.Sum(item => +item.Value) / 5; this line

Answer (score 0):

```cs
double average = num2.Sum(item => item.Value) / 5; // Delete '+' before item.Value
double curve = 75.0 - average; // 75 is int, 75.0 - double
```

P.S. Why are you using `SortedList`?